# Using ansible vsphere_guest to assign Custom Attribute to virtual machine

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ansible

I'm using ansible to automate deploys from templates in vSphere 6.0

I'm looking for a way to set/modify a custom attribute to a VM using ansible.

As far as I understand, there is no option in the module vsphere_guest to do so. I'm looking at Ansible's official docs here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html

Do you have any clues on this? vsphere API has that functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_guest_module.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set

> A key, value pair of any extra values you want set or changed in the vmx file of the VM. Useful to set advanced options on the VM.

with the `vm_extra_config` parameter of the [vsphere_guest_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html).